# What shapes would an elliptical conic section produce?

Tags: conic-sections

If the cone(s) we slice with a plane to produce the various conic section shapes (ellipses, circles, parabolas, hyperbolas, lines) were not cones but instead, cone like shapes that had an elliptical base instead of a circular one, what shapes would be produced?

(By an elliptical cone I mean one that would produce an ellipse on a plane positioned perpendicular to the midline of the conic instead of a circle.)

I'm an artist, and I've sketched some pictures to try to visualize the intersections.  It looks like I can get the same set of conics, but I can't verify that my drawings are in proper perspective.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You still get "regular" conics. As with a circular cone, and elliptical cone corresponds to a degree-$2$ polynomial equation in $x$, $y$, $z$; a plane is defined by a degree-$1$ equation. Therefore, their intersection is then a plane curve of degree $2\cdot 1=2$ (relative to a $2$D coordinate system on the plane), and we *know* that all of those are our familiar conics. (BTW: The same argument works when the cone is replaced by *any* surface determined by a degree-$2$ polynomial. Such surfaces are called ["quadrics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric).)

Comment: I am coming to the mathematics community as more of an artist than a mathematician. I am curious about this because I have wondered what shapes ellipses would make in a perspective drawing (imagine trying to draw a wall with ellipses inscribed into it). What I have tried is just drawing the shapes but don't actually know how to validate if my shapes are drawn in correct perspective, which is why I need the help of the mathematics community. @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Thank you @Blue, it sounds like this could potentially be an answer if you wanted to post it. I did not know about quadrics until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale transformation of the (circular) cone becomes an elliptical cone.

[image]

The intersections are merely scaled versions of the quadratic intersections in the base case, i.e., circles, ellipses, hyperbolas, parabolas, ...

[image]

Comment: When you say oval do you mean ellipse?

Comment: Yes.  Here oval = ellipse.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you really produce an ellipse by scaling a circle? I would love to see a proof of that.

Comment: Oh gee... I gather you're really quite a novice in math.  That a scaled circle is an ellipse is usually presented in 9th-grade math class.  I'm sure you can find the proof online or in high-school books.